# Does Wordpress create mobile menus automatically?

Tags: menus, themes, mobile

I am using Wordpress 4.5.2 with a custom theme. I am a bit confused about WP and the theme customizations, what does the first and what the second.
For example, fullscreen menus are managed by WP.....what about mobile menus? Are they generated automatically by WP or this is done in the theme?

Comment: It's done (added, stylized) entirely by theme usually using [`wp_nav_menu`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/).

Comment: This means that ordinary wordpress menu will not be responsive on mobile devices?

Comment: You're right, that's generally the philosophy of WordPress: _e.g_ this function spits out the basic `HTML` and it's either theme's author or your job to make it look and function like you want or need.

Comment: Thanks a lot. If you will reply as an answer I will check it as the solution

Answer (score 1):

The default Wordpress themes, from [Twenty Eleven](https://wordpress.org/themes/twentyeleven/) onwards, support varying degrees of responsive design, including menus, and any child themes will automatically inherit this behaviour, unless the child theme does something to override it.

It is possible to create menus in your theme using [wp_nav_menu](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/) that can then be hidden or displayed for various screen widths or device types in your css rules, giving the theme creator complete control over responsive behaviour.